# Dr Who : Extremis - why do the portals open?

Tags: doctor-who

In Dr Who: Extremis, why do the portals seem to open for no apparent reason.

When Billy and Nardole went and checked on the gun shot and then turned around the portal opened for no reason.

Then when the Doctor was chased and losing his sight a portal opened for no reason as well.

My question is, why did the portals open? or did I missed something?

Comment: I thought that's how the monks/zombies/demons/whatever entered the room...

Comment: @tilley31 - Yes, I agree that's how the monks/zombies/demons/whatever entered the rooms, but still doesn't explain why they automatically opened for Billy/Nardole or the Dr - (eg for Billy and Nardole there were no "monks/zombies" present when the portal opened - also the portal just decided to open for story progression).

Comment: Just a theory, but maybe the portals don't open one by one, maybe they all activate at the same time. And that someone who opened them might have gone through to somewhere else and Billy & Nardole just got lucky. And later on when the Doctor enters the portal, it might have been left open when the creatures entered the library.

Comment: @Renttutar - Your theory seems plausible, but if I recall the portal that the Dr goes through just automatically opened when he was in a need to escape. I believe, although I don't have any evidence that these portals were just opened for basic story progression... it's annoying to watch the episode with such a big loop hole knowing that the episode could have ended with the Dr being wiped from the simulation within the Vatican archives and therefore the Dr couldn't have sent his "email".

Comment: I just rewatched that part of the episode. The Doctor is running, and yes the portal opens when he is close to it. But we can't actually see why it opens, we just see the blue light. But I think it opens because the creatures are close enough. Therefore there isn't any switch or remote to open them, all it needs is one of the creatures to approach it and that triggers the activation. That actually fits in my earlier theory too.

Comment: Maybe one or more creatures have to be through the portal for it to open when someone gets close. And when the father (or cardinal or whatever) feels the wall, none of them are in the library. Bill and Nardole goes through after the father has been killed by one of the creatures, and the creature stayed in after the killing. (I hope my text is understandable, sometimes I have trouble with english sentences :P) I don't have any proof, so that's why I don't add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

We discover in the episode that **they are not really 'portals' at all**. What initially seems to be a network of portals leading back to a central hub is eventually recognised by Nardole as a set of 'projectors' creating 11 virtual worlds. That means that the 'portals' as seen from within those virtual worlds are the starting point of the projected simulation. It would not be possible to walk past that point and not leave that area of the simulation, whether the portal was visible or not.

Of course, this doesn't explain why the 'portals' appear to open at certain times, but it could be presumed that, as they are fixed points and it is impossible to walk past them without entering the projection hub, there is some point or angle at which they become visible? Whatever explanation you might prefer, it fits Nardole's discovery that the portals are there even if they cannot be seen.